# Which statement is more efficient between with or without additional condition when updating a row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am using mysql database, and now I must make sure that a value in a column should be `1` while it may be `1` already. So, considering the following two statements:

```
UPDATE category SET is_leaf=1 WHERE id=9
```

or

```
UPDATE category SET is_leaf=1 WHERE id=9 AND is_leaf=0
```

`id` is the primary key, the difference is when is_leaf is already 1, then to update it or not, which is more efficient?

I know it doesn't matter a lot, but I want to find out to better understanding mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query with the `AND is_leaf=0` included can be more efficient sometimes.

It's not going to make much difference when locating the row based on the primary key. (The availability of an index  `on (id,is_leaf)` might make a small difference.) But as soon as MySQL identifies that there is no row to be updated, it can take a shorter code path.

Absent that predicate, however, MySQL is going to have to locate the row, obtain a row lock (in the case of InnoDB), and fire any 'BEFORE UPDATE FOR EACH ROW' trigger. Then MySQL has to check if any column values are actually being changed (note that the execution of the trigger may be setting one or more columns to different values).  If MySQL detects there is no change to the row, it can skip the setting of any 'ON UPDATE' timestamp column, fire off any 'AFTER UPDATE FOR EACH ROW' trigger, and set the affected rows count to zero. (In the context of a transaction, it's not clear if MySQL can release the row lock once it determines the row is not being changed, or whether a row lock will continue to be held until the commit or rollback.)

So, one big difference between the two statements is that MySQL will fire the 'FOR EACH ROW' triggers even if there are no actual changes to the row; but it won't fire any 'FOR EACH ROW' triggers for rows that are excluded by the WHERE clause.

In the simple case, absent any triggers, I don't expect there is any measurable difference in performance.

My personal preference is to include the extra predicate. This ensures that no (InnoDB) intent row locks will be requested or held, and no FOR EACH ROW triggers will be fired.

---

And apart from the row locking and trigger execution, as far as those two statements being exactly the same, they aren't really. At least not in the general case, where there is a possibility that `is_leaf` can contain a NULL or a value other than 0 or 1.

Given this statement:

```
UPDATE category SET is_leaf=1 WHERE id=9
```

For an equivalent statement that sets `is_leaf` to 1 whenever it is not already equal to 1, we would actually need to check for NULL and any value different than 1, such as:

```
UPDATE category SET is_leaf=1 WHERE id=9 AND NOT (is_leaf <=> 1)
```

Consider what happens when `is_leaf` is NULL or 2, for example, with this statement:

```
UPDATE category SET is_leaf=1 WHERE id=9 AND is_leaf=0
```

Comment: When we set a value to be `1` while it is already `1`, then mysql will 1)check whether it will be changed actually and then decide to update it or not; or 2)update it anyway, and then monitor whether it has been changed? If it is the first situation, then I think the two statements are doing the exactly same thing(except the second statement requires less row locks).

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE category SET is_leaf=1 WHERE id=9 AND is_leaf=0
```

is more efficient. because then it update only relevant data.  otherwise even if the `is_leaf=1` records are also going to update.

Assume that there are 1000 record on the table and it take 1s to update one record. if u trying to update all records then it will take 1000 S. but assume in this scenario there are  `is_leaf=0` record count is 150 then if you use this second statement it will take only 150 seconds instead of 1000 s.

Edit :

**Queries With Search Arguments (SARGs)**

A WHERE clause helps you to restrict the number of rows returned by a query. However, the manner in which the WHERE condition is specified can impact the performance of the query. If the WHERE condition is written such that it uses a function that takes an indexed column as the input, then the index is ignored and the entire table is scanned. This results in performance degradation.
For example, the following results in a table scan because the column OrderDate is used in a function:

```
SELECT CustomerID, EmployeeID FROM Orders
WHERE DATEDIFF(m, OrderDate, GetDate())>3
```

If the function is rewritten as shown below, then the query seeks the required value using an index and this improves performance:

```
SELECT CustomerID, EmployeeID FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate < DATEADD(m, -3, GetDate())
```

The filter criteria in the second query is said to use a Searchable Argument or SARG because the query optimizer can use an index seek operation during execution.

for more information about this you better read [improving query performance](http://www.sqlsteps.com/sql-tutorial-improving-query-performance)

and also read this for [Speeding up Searches and Filters](http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/speedupsearchesandfilters.htm)

Comment: Is there any experimental evidence supporting this? Because the additional conditions take more time to check, for example, check whether its value is 0 and then update it or just update it without checking, the problem is which costs more, checking or updating?